# Ubuntu KVM guest uses only 1 out of N cores - even under load

Tags: 12.04, kvm-virtualization

I have a web application server running Ubuntu 12.04 as a KVM guest.

What I have seen is that even under heavy load only one core is being used extensively. It is not an issue of the application not being multi-threaded. We are running `nginx` and `php-fpm` on these servers and I have tested on Cent-OS that these applications do run on all cores when heavily loaded.
Here are the particulars:

```
/usr/bin/kvm -S -M pc-1.0 -enable-kvm -m 20480 -smp 6,sockets=6,cores=1,threads=1 -name 
db1 -uuid 02af7f56-16ea-76cc-81f8-b5fa24993843d6 -nodefconfig -nodefaults -chardev 
socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/db1.monitor,server,nowait -mon 
chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc -no-shutdown -drive file=/dev
/vg0/db1,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=raw,cache=none -device virtio-
blk-pci,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 -drive file=/dev/vg0/db1_vol2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk1,format=raw,cache=none -device virtio-
blk-pci,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6,drive=drive-virtio-disk1,id=virtio-disk1 -drive file=/dev
/vg1/db1_mysql,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk2,format=raw,cache=none -device virtio-
blk-pci,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7,drive=drive-virtio-disk2,id=virtio-disk2 -drive 
if=none,media=cdrom,id=drive-ide0-1-0,readonly=on,format=raw -device 
ide-drive,bus=ide.1,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-1-0,id=ide0-1-0 -netdev 
tap,fd=18,id=hostnet0,vhost=on,vhostfd=19 -device virtio-
net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:b5:51:1e,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev 
pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -usb -vnc 
127.0.0.1:0 -k en-us -vga cirrus -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5
```

Why is that? I understand the scheduler will try its best to keep things running quick, but I do not see this behavior in RHEL based servers.

Comment: No one have any info. As I review the configuration of other servers in this build I see the same results time and time again. Under heavy load, only a single CPU shows any sign of being used. The function does not matter. I see servers running as firewall on bare metal, showing the same symptoms. I am wondering if it is a problem with the hardware or with this version of Ubuntu. My Goggle searches have turned up nothing, hence my posting here.